# how to configure apache flume agent with webserver for window

Tags: flume

I am able to configure an agent for window but i have a confusion regarding connectivity between web servers logs with agent.

1: How to connect web server with agent ?

2: while starting flume.bat file. It is generating flume.log file in which i am getting below  mentioned Exception.

**org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: No channel configured for sink: hdfssink
at org.apache.flume.conf.sink.SinkConfiguration.configure(SinkConfiguration.java:51)**
atorg.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSinks(FlumeConfiguration.java:661)

Answer (score 1):

1.The data flow is as below

your application (or web server) --> source --> channel --> sink

Now, the data can flow from your **webserver** to the **source** either by "pull" mechanism or "push" mechanism. In your case, you can either tail the webserver logs or use a spooling source.

2.This looks like a misconfiguration issue. You need to post your config file to figure out the issue